# keyboard displays within tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift

I changed my view controllers to Tab Bars.Now for some reason, the keyboard does not display past the toolbar at the bottom and all I see is the done button. I am not even sure what code to post. When I used a navigation controller the keyboard opened up. I used the attribute inspector to set the keyboard type

Comment: Just in case, are you testing on the simulator? The keyboard might be hidden, since a hardware keyboard is simulated. Press `⌘K` to toggle the keyboard.

Comment: Thank that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard might be hidden in the simulator, since a hardware keyboard is simulated. Press ⌘K to toggle the keyboard.